# Как сделать чтобы ArrayList<Integer> limitedStack в классе LimitedStack.java был не static и программа работала?

Tags: java, arraylist, static

Сейчас код рабочий , однако , необходимо сделать чтобы limitedStack был не static.

```
public class ConsumerThread implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public  void  run() {

        while (!interrupted()) {

                LimitedStack limitedStack = new LimitedStack();
                limitedStack.pop();
                System.out.println(LimitedStack.limitedStack.size() + " elements in stack, removed last element from stack by " + Thread.currentThread());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception in" + Thread.currentThread());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
          }
     }
}

public class LimitedStack {

    static  ArrayList<Integer> limitedStack = new ArrayList(Main.stackCapacity);


    public synchronized void push(int randomValue) {

            if (limitedStack.size() < Main.stackCapacity ) {
                limitedStack.add(randomValue);
            } else try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public synchronized int pop() {

            if (limitedStack.size() >= 1) {
                return limitedStack.remove(limitedStack.size() - 1);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;

    }    
}



public class Main {
    static Integer stackCapacity;

    public   static void  main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter  maximum number of elements in stack:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        stackCapacity = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You change maximum size of elements in stack to " + stackCapacity);
        System.out.println("Current value of elements in limitedStack is " + LimitedStack.limitedStack.size());

        Thread manufacturerThread1 = new Thread(new ManufacturerThread());
        Thread manufacturerThread2 = new Thread(new ManufacturerThread());
        Thread manufacturerThread3 = new Thread(new ManufacturerThread());
        Thread consumerThread1 = new Thread(new ConsumerThread());
        Thread consumerThread2 = new Thread(new ConsumerThread());
        Thread consumerThread3 = new Thread(new ConsumerThread());

        try {
            manufacturerThread1.start();
            Thread.sleep(10);
            manufacturerThread2.start();
            Thread.sleep(10);
            manufacturerThread3.start();
            Thread.sleep(10);
            consumerThread1.start();
            Thread.sleep(10);
            consumerThread2.start();
            Thread.sleep(10);
            consumerThread3.start();
            Thread.sleep(10);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in Main");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public  class ManufacturerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public   void run() {
        while (!interrupted()) {

                Integer value;
                Random randomValue = new Random();
                value = randomValue.nextInt(200);

                LimitedStack limitedStack = new LimitedStack();
                limitedStack.push(value);
                System.out.println(LimitedStack.limitedStack.size() + " elements in stack , pushed element " + value + " in stack" + "by" + Thread.currentThread());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception in " + Thread.currentThread());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
      }
 }
```

Comment: А что будет, когда `limitedStack` будет не static?

Comment: Программа будет работать неправильно , будут выводиться не те значения , т.к. объекты LimitedStack limitedStack в классах ConsumerThread и ManufacturerThread будут менять объекты не одной статической коллекции , а  фактически объекты разных коллекций с одним именем .

Comment: А разве каждый поток для себя не делает копию этой переменной при статике? Т.е. оно разве сейчас то разве работает правильно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Сейчас там все экземпляры объекта `LimitedStack` (которые каждый раз создаются) ссылаются на один и тот же список, ибо `static`. Поэтому все как бы работает (но чудом, поскольку с синхронизацией беда)

Comment: @zRrr `но чудом, поскольку с синхронизацией беда` - вот я примерно на это и намекаю

Comment: А что бы сделать чтобы пофиксить проблемы с синхронизацией?

Comment: @АртёмРуфеев если вопрос **только** в изменении поля статик то тут много простых решений.Для начала оцените этап на котором возникает необходимость объявить данное поле статичным - у Вас есть необходимость иметь доступ к одному хранилищу данных для разных потоков. Соответственно достаточно логичный ход в каждый новый поток **передавать** ссылку на один и тот же экземпляр хранилища к примеру: добавьте в `Thread manufacturerThread1 = new Thread(new ManufacturerThread(limitedStack));` где `LimitedStack limitedStack = new LimitedStack();`